# Nautilus - screen tearing after scrolling

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, nautilus

When I scroll in Nautilus some entries don't refresh properly.

[image: Nautilus with corrupted entry]

It doesn't matter if I scroll with the scroll wheel on my mouse or with page-up, page-down, home or end keys. It doesn't happen if I scroll with the arrow keys though.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit all the latest updates installed. I have a Intel Core i7 920 and a Geforce GTX 570 installed. I am using the nvidia-331 driver provided by Ubuntu.

Any hints on how to investigate this further are welcome.

Comment: Is this occassional issue, or for any scrolling?

Comment: @david6 I can reproduce it with any folder with enough entries to scroll.

Comment: @david6 It only happens with scrolling within nautilus

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I no longer have it since I installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.

The following solved it for [someone else](https://askubuntu.com/a/760819/110181), so you might want to try it:

Add the following

```
__GL_YIELD="USLEEP"
KWIN_TRIPLE_BUFFER=0
KWIN_USE_BUFFER_AGE=0
```

to `/etc/environment`.