# Screen Tearing After Kubuntu Upgrade 15.10 -> 16.04

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, tearing

Just upgraded today, already regretting it. I have terrible VSync/tearing problems. Before it worked flawlessly.

I already tried all compositor settings, some of them seemed to temporarily remove tearing, but after about a minute I could notice it again.

In addition to that I can't enter my full-disk-encryption password when it starts the GUI version, only when I reset the PC and it starts the fallback CLI version.

GPU: GTX 780
CPU: i7 4790k
Screens: 3x 1080p (DVI-I + DVI-D + DP -> DVI)

Driver: Latest Proprietary Nvidia Driver (just updated today after upgrading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution For The Tearing Problem

As [/u/ropid](https://www.reddit.com/u/ropid) suggested, I tried adding this

```
__GL_YIELD="USLEEP"
KWIN_TRIPLE_BUFFER=0
KWIN_USE_BUFFER_AGE=0
```

to `/etc/environment`.

This fixed the tearing issue for me.

## Solution For The Encryption Problem

I found [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1385027), which suggested to do the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then replace

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

This disabled the GUI password prompt. The CLI version successfully detects my keyboard.

Comment: The _solution for the tearing problem_ listed above worked but had some artifacting with my Kubuntu 16.04 installation on an Intel i7-2600K Sandybridge processor with Intel integrated HD 3000 graphics.  I posted a solution that worked better for me at [Screen Tearing on Kubuntu 16.04 with Intel Drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764302/screen-tearing-on-kubuntu-16-04-with-intel-drivers/774788)