# Screen Tearing on Kubuntu 16.04 with Intel Drivers?

Tags: kubuntu, screen, intel, tearing

So, quick background, on Kubuntu and have massive screen tearing issues. I have never had these problems on any other Linux Distros. Videos look really choppy, overall it's not a good experience. I have recently switched over from Windows, and don't know how to update/install drivers on Ubuntu. I just know I have Intel... Sorry if I am being vague, but that's all I got.

Comment: Post the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` please.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced video tearing with Kubuntu 16.04 on my Intel i7-2600K Sandybridge processor with integrated Intel HD 3000 Graphics.

**SOLUTION A**:  Best solution

1. Start *K -> Settings -> System Settings*
2. Under *Hardware* section double-click *Display and Monitor*
3. Choose *Compositor* on LHS and ensure:

   ```
   Enable compositor on startup:  Checked   # was enabled by default
   Tearing prevention ("vsync"):  Full screen repaints   # was Automatic
   ```

   Note:  *Ignore message "Full screen repaints" can cause performance problems.*

   Do not use **Re-use screen content** on Intel Graphics!
4. Click Apply

This completely fixed the problem for me.  There was no video tearing in full screen or in a window, and there was no artifacting.

See [Bug 321589 - Automatic VSync strategy causes tearing](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=321589)

**SOLUTION B**:

Edit **/etc/environment** and add the following lines:

```
__GL_YIELD="USLEEP"
KWIN_USE_BUFFER_AGE=0
```

Save the file and reboot.

This fixed the problem for me with full screen videos.  There is; however, occasional tearing with videos in a window.  There was no artifacting with these settings.

**BACKGROUND**:

I discovered the three variables to try, which were listed as working for NVidia graphics, at the following link:
[Screen Tearing After Kubuntu Upgrade 15.10 -> 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760738/screen-tearing-after-kubuntu-upgrade-15-10-16-04)

```
__GL_YIELD="USLEEP"
KWIN_TRIPLE_BUFFER=0
KWIN_USE_BUFFER_AGE=0
```

The above three lines did prevent video tearing, but I experienced some artifacting with some non-video playing activities, such as editing a file with emacs.  Hence I experimented some more and found a better compromise.

For a description of these KDE variables see [KWin/Environment Variables](https://community.kde.org/KWin/Environment_Variables).

Later on I discovered the **Full screen repaints** setting which completely resolved all issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Kubuntu 16.04 I solved it by changing the **Rendering backend**

Go to System Settings > Display and Monitor > Compositor(in the side bar) > change rendering engine to OpenGL 3.1

Comment: This fixed it for me too (ubuntu 18.10)